# Android MediaPlayer - onBufferingUpdate called with 100 before called with 0

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

The code below is a minimal example of an Activity hosting a MediaPlayer to play an MP3 stream from a URL.  Pressing "btn1" triggers URL1 to play (an NPR podcast).  Pressing "btn2" triggers URL2 to play (mp3 recording of a different station).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    static final String URL1 = "http://13503.mc.tritondigital.com/WAITWAIT_PODCAST/media-session/822d578a-af47-4d7e-b3ca-d18af78071bc/anon.npr-podcasts/podcast/344098539/464996449/npr_464996449.mp3";
    static final String URL2 = "http://www.selbie.com/wrekapp/Fri0130.mp3";

    MediaPlayer _player;

    void startPlayerAsync(String url) {

        stopPlayer();  // _player.reset(); _player.release(); _player=null;

        Log.d(TAG, "===================");
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting new player for URL: "+url);

        _player = new MediaPlayer();

        try
        {
            _player.setDataSource(url);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException", e);
            return;
        }

        _player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate: " + percent);
            }
        });

        _player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (mp == _player)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared");
                    _player.start();
                }
            }
        });

        _player.prepareAsync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startPlayerAsync(URL1);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.btn2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startPlayerAsync(URL2);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

When btn1 is clicked, a summary of the logspew prior to hearing audio is the following:

```
02-28 19:47:43.764 D/MainActivity: ===================
02-28 19:47:43.764 D/MainActivity: Starting new player for URL: http://13503.mc.tritondigital.com/WAITWAIT_PODCAST/media-session/822d578a-af47-4d7e-b3ca-d18af78071bc/anon.npr-podcasts/podcast/344098539/464996449/npr_464996449.mp3
02-28 19:47:44.695 1D/MainActivity: OnBufferingUpdate: 0
02-28 19:47:44.697 D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
02-28 19:47:44.699 D/MainActivity: onPrepared
02-28 19:47:44.703 D/MainActivity: onBufferingUpdate: 0
02-28 19:47:45.703 D/MainActivity: onBufferingUpdate: 6
02-28 19:47:46.704 D/MainActivity: onBufferingUpdate: 9
...
```

When btn2 is pressed for the other URL, there's a slightly different behavior:

```
02-28 19:47:18.892 D/MainActivity: ===================
02-28 19:47:18.893 D/MainActivity: Starting new player for URL: http://www.selbie.com/wrekapp/Fri0130.mp3
02-28 19:47:20.453 D/MainActivity: onBufferingUpdate: 100     <==== NOTICE THIS
02-28 19:47:20.453 D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
02-28 19:47:20.465 D/MainActivity: onPrepared
02-28 19:47:20.676 D/MainActivity: onBufferingUpdate: 0
02-28 19:47:21.680 D/MainActivity: onBufferingUpdate: 2
...
```

In the first case, there is an early `onBufferingUpdate(0)` event fired prior to `onPrepared`. Then a periodic interval of `onBufferingUpdate` calls incrementing from 0 to 100 as the stream plays.

But in the second case, there is a spurious `onBufferingUpdate(100)` event fired. But a few seconds later it's corrected with an `onBufferingUpdate(0)` after `onPrepared`.

It does not matter which button the user clicked on first or which stream gets started.  I've even moved the mp3 file of URL2 from its original server to another one.  There's something about the mp3 stream of the second URL that causes MediaPlayer to want to behave this way.  In my actual application, this causes the "secondary progress" line of my progress control to show a solid line for a second before it shows the expected buffering.  It's a visual blemish on the app.

My workaround is to ignore all `onBufferingUpdate` events until after `onPrepared` is fired.  Before I make that change, I'd like to get some insight into why this happens. And to make sure its safe to assume that there can't be a legitimate case where buffering gets to 100% prior to the stream being started. Is this the right fix?

Comment: Seems like there are issues with the media player Callback as mentioned here (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65564). It's good that you posted your solution and workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given no other option, I decided to simply ignore any call to onBufferingUpdate with a value of 100 when the MediaPlayer is in the *preparing* state and hasn't been called with a non-zero value before:

Effectively, the code becomes this:

```
    _player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

             // percent can be something awkward like "-2147483648" on a live source. Just clamp it.
            if (percent < 0) {
               percent = 0;
            }
            else if (percent > 100) {
                percent = 100;
            }

            if ((_state == Preparing) && (_secondaryPercent == 0) && (percent == 100)) {
                  Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate(100) invoked while in preparing state - ignoring");
            }
            else if (_secondaryPercent != percent) {
                _secondaryPercent = percent;
                handleBufferingUpdate(percent);
            }
        }
    });
```